# Can anyone help me in this python code for finding Cube

Tags: python

```
x=3
y=x
ans=0

while( y != 0 ):
  ans = ans + x
  y = y - 1
ans = ans*x
print( str(ans) )
```

There is no output on screen. And no error is showing up. Just shown in image.

[image]

Comment: Are the first two lines accurate? You should use a lowercase x and y, otherwise you are creating two variables, `x` and `X`.

Comment: if you change your variables to be consistent (*e.g.* make sure you always use `X` or `x`, capitalization matters), your code would be fine

Comment: Sorry its writing mistake here

Comment: Voting to close, code works after fixing typo.

Comment: Sir you can run that...if it..then you can vote to close...

Comment: @Ravi, the code prints [27](https://www.google.com/search?q=3*3*3&oq=3*3*3). what is your expected output?

Comment: Are you aware that `3**3` evaluates to 27 in the Python interpreter? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Sir I want to run that with repetitive addition method

Comment: How are you trying to execute the program?

Comment: Pressing F5 on python idle

Comment: Isn't idle a REPL? Try saving to a file and executing from the command line.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked ! New thing learned 

Comment: your code also works in IDLE @Ravi https://i.imgur.com/TDcmBgV.png

Comment: Sorry...But didn't worked in my IDLE that's why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only works for 3 cubed. You're also using multiplication. If you only want only addition as your comment implies, you'll probably want to break down your logic a bit. Here's how I'd do it (stop reading here and try to work it out yourself, first!):

```
def cube(x):
    """ Calculate x to the 3rd power (cube) """
    x_times_x = multiply(x, x)
    x2_times_x = multiply(x_times_x, x)
    return x2_times_x

def multiply(x, y):
    """ Multiplies two numbers only using addition """
    accum = 0
    for _ in range(y):
        accum += x
    return accum

print(cube(3))
print(cube(4))
print(cube(5))
```

Outputs:

```
27
64
125
```

as expected. Remember the easiest way to see output is to just save code to a file and run `python` from your command line.

Comment: Thanks for your help...but I'm beginner dont know about functions...but I will surely try to understand

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is all off.

You're using a capital X on the first line, then suddenly it's lowercase on the 2nd line.

`while` loops in python are generally written like this:

`while y != 0 :`

Comment: Still didn't get the output